# jQuery toggleClass not working with bootstrap collapse (change Icon/Class)

Tags: jquery

I'm working with bootstrap 3 and the collapse function.
If I click on my `plus-icon` the collapse-panel will be shown. Another click and the panel will be close. Works!

But I want to `toggleClass` my Icon .. onclick change to `imgMinus` (open collapse), click again, change to `imgPlus` (close collapse).

[Here's my fiddle ...](http://jsfiddle.net/mobilat/02o08heq/)

I try to `addClass` and `removeClass`.. nothing works ...?

My snippet works, if I had only one Content Container, but not with both!

```
$('.clickToggle').click(function() {
           /*if ($(this).children('div').hasClass("imgPlus")) {
             $(this).children('div').addClass("imgMinus");
             $(this).children('div').removeClass("imgPlus");
          }*/

          $(this).children('div').toggleClass('imgPlus imgMinus');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close! I removed the script tags from your html and put it in the JavaScript section of the fiddle. Then I removed the extra script for the click toggle.

Little confusing to say so here is the fiddle lemme know if this solves it!
The code below is the only script you need to change from + to - and vice versa
http://jsfiddle.net/02o08heq/31/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.clickToggle').click(function() {
        $(this).children('div').toggleClass('imgPlus imgMinus');
    });
});
```

Also in your fiddle you had addClass when I believe you meant toggleClass( even though your code snippet had it )

Comment: you're right .. thank you. the code was right, but on the wrong place .. now it's at my `main.js`-file.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to hear that it works, you were definitely close, just needed another pair of eyes :)

Answer (score 0):

Before  add:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.clickToggle').click(function() {
            $(this).find('div').toggleClass("imgMinus");
            $(this).find('div').toggleClass("imgPlus");
        });
    });
</script>
```

And so will work!